# Object oriented Javascript, why won't an object's methods work from within my init method?

Tags: javascript, oop

This code is adapted from mozilla's intro to object oriented js page: [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

When I run the following javascript code, I don't get the "hello" alert indicating that sayHello was called correctly. In the mozilla docs, the creation and calling of the person objects does not fall into an init function- which I copied into the bottom example. What gives?

```
window.onload = init();

function init()
{
    var person1 = new Person('Male');
    var person2 = new Person('Female');

    // call the Person sayHello method.
    person1.sayHello(); // hello
}

function Person(gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
  alert('Person instantiated');
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function()
{
  alert ('hello');
};
```

working example:

```
function Person(gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
  alert('Person instantiated');
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function()
{
  alert ('hello');
};

var person1 = new Person('Male');
var person2 = new Person('Female');

// call the Person sayHello method.
person1.sayHello(); // hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = init();
```

There's your problem. This runs the `init` method, then applies the return value (`undefined`) as the `onload` property of the `window`.  So nothing happens `onload`; everything happens immediately. This means that it happens before you modify `Person.prototype`.

Do this instead to delay execution:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: You also need to do that line after defining the `init` function, not before.

Comment: @DarkFalcon `init` is a function declaration, so will be hoisted.

Comment: Although I agree, it's best to declare functions at the top of their containing scope.

Comment: this works, and it seems to work whether or not that line lives before or after the init declaration.